A single symbol or notation means many things - does this actually cause problems for learners?
This is a somewhat abstract and ill-formed question, but I hope the examples clarify it.
The question concerns a common pattern in didactic literature.
For example:

The equal sign has several different meanings, like assigning a value and comparing things. The notation for these is the same.
The minus sign has several different meanings, like subtraction, the sign of a number and multiplication by minus one.
Sometimes this is more abstract, such as in so-called abuses of notation, where $x^3$ is a function and we do measure theory on it, rather than the equivalence class. And we just gave a formula, not a function, which requires specifying where the function is defined, where it maps to, and which letter is the variable there.

The common factor in these situations is that notation hides complexity or distinctions.
A thing I see in didactic literature is teasing these apart, which is all well and good.
The question: do these situations where notation hides complexity cause problems for learners?
An alternative hypothesis is that pupils and students find, say, the equal sign difficult for some other reason, which is not really related to this hidden complexity. It is known, for example, that pupils mostly see the equal sign in tasks such as 3 + 18 = ? , so they learn it means that "the result or next step in the calculation is". But seeing a thing often and thus learning the most obvious usage is a different reason for difficulties than the concept itself having hidden complexity, for example the assignment and the comparison. Note that "the result or next step in the calculation is" is not really mathematically accepted definition of the equality sign. Some kind of arrow might sometimes be used for this purpose, at least on blackboard work, but not really the equal sign.
Or maybe they are the same thing. This is what I am asking for.
A positive answer could refer to research that shows how many misconceptions are related to fundamental structures hidden by notation. A negative answer would show that most misconceptions have their root in some other phenomenon than the concept in question having many different and hidden meanings.

In general, $-a$ is a number that added to $a$ gives zero. In particular, $-1$ is a number that added to $1$ gives zero. Therefore, in the "multiplication by minus one" property $(-1)a=-a$ the minus signs have the same meaning. Furthermore, the subtraction $a-b$ is just a shorthand for the addition $a+(-b)$, where again the minus sign has the same meaning as before. So I think your second point is not completely clear. And it seems that similar comments could be made for the other points.

@Pedro The list of meanings of subtraction is from a textbook by van de Walle and others, intended for primary school teacher students.

My gut feel is that students who are weak in one area tend to be weak in several.  So, I strongly doubt that different notation would solve the problems they are having generally.  Instead significant drill and reinforcement is needed in many areas (fractions, negative numbers, etc.)  Also, I would be wary of being too fussy/precise about the different issues here...as it may be easier to learn in context, versus with a long instruction set.  Consider how we learn homonyms for instance.

P.s.  (Mostly for fun, but with some side intentions also.)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k_jS1zVLWw

The words "there", "they're", and "their" are all the same in spoken language--does this cause confusion?  "Read" (present tense) and "read" (past tense) have the same spelling, but different pronunciation---does this cause confusion?  All language, including mathematics, has ambiguity, and part of teaching someone a new language is helping them to understand and work through that ambiguity.

I don't have any research references handy, though I'm sure many exist for this question (particularly for the difference between a function and an expression in writing things like $x^3+1$).  However, one I can vouch very clearly causes trouble in my own experience is the use of parentheses in American mathematics education.

Parentheses mean grouping, which may or may not be associative: $2^{\left(2^3\right)}\neq \left(2^2\right)^3$
Parentheses mean functions: $f(x)=x^2+1$
Parentheses mean multiplication: $2(3)=6$

Unfortunately, especially the latter two are often confused - often enough that the "If I had a dollar for each time ..." cliche might actually hold true.  Why?  Some examples of miscomprehension I come across every year:

If $f(x)=3x$ then $f=3$
If $g(5)=30$ then $g(10)=60$, even if $g(x)=x^2+5$
If $\ln(x)$ is the notation then $\ln(x+y)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$ must be true.
A related issue is pronunciation of "f of x" as "f x" or even "f times x".

I'm not saying these problems couldn't show up in other ways, but the implicit linearity one gets from the similarity of these notations is pretty aggravating, as an educator, and surely frustrating to students who are tripped up by it.  The function concept is hard enough (note that it took Euler to first use it sort of properly) without having its notation shared by something else important.

Side note: My understanding is that in a lot of the Commonwealth/UK the last meaning of parentheses (brackets in the UK?) is not anywhere near as common, writing instead $2.3$ or something.  I'd love to see precise evidence of when the parenthesis convention became popular in the United States (and perhaps elsewhere).

The notation 2(3) is foreign to me in the Finnish, Norwegian and research mathematics contexts and would make a nice question, if it has not been asked already.

@Tommi ... I assume in Finnish & Norwegian you do have things like $2(x+y)$.

AIUI, the parens in ‘2(3)’ aren't a separate notation at all.  They're simply for grouping (your first meaning) — in this case, a group holding a single number.  The multiplication is the same implicit function you get from concatenating any two expressions, just as for 2 or -(-1) or ( + )( + ).

@GeraldEdgar Yes, brackets are used as normal. But for multiplication of numbers one uses a symbol for multiplication between the numbers.

@gidds - correct, but it's a sloppy one, because of the ambiguity.  If we always wrote $(2)(3)$ instead it would be very clear that grouping is involved.  In principle this ambiguity isn't (fully) present with $2x$ or $2(x+y)$, though I think an argument could be made to require $(2)(x)$ or at least $(2)(x+y)$ - if that ship hadn't long ago sailed!

If I ever talk about the function $1(x)$ I'll make triply sure they understand I mean the function that maps $x \to 1$ for all $x$.
